# Feed a function a specific character to use in variable names?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you add a function to jQuery like so:

```
     $.fn.boxLoader = function() {
            var FilterSelect = ($("[id^='filter_a_selector_']"));
            // do things to FilterSelect
            return this;
    });
```

And then when a specific action happens, I run that function.

I have multiple elements with these names:

```
#filter_a_selector_1
#filter_b_selector_1
#filter_a_selector_2
#filter_b_selector_2
```

So I am using the ^ selector to select them all regardless if ending in 1 or 2, but how can I feed the function an "a" or a "b" depending on the need?

I want to be able to run that function on filter_b_selector_ too in some situations, without having to duplicate the function and call it something new + only change the filter_a_selector to have a "b" in it.

So ideally it'd look something like this:

```
 $.fn.boxLoader = function(filter_a_or_b) {
            var FilterSelect = ($("[id^='filter_{filter_a_or_b}_selector_']"));
            // do things to FilterSelect
            return this;
    });
```

Or similar

Comment: You should really learn how to use classes...

Comment: I can't use classes in this case, the id/classes come from something that I don't control and there are multiple elements that are all different and need an ID to be targetted. I simplified the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery accept string concatenation :

```
 $.fn.boxLoader = function(filter_a_or_b) {
        var FilterSelect = ($("[id^='filter_"+ filter_a_or_b + "_selector_']"));
        // do things to FilterSelect
        return this;
 });
```

Comment: @JanDvorak didn't say it perform, i said it accept and meant you *can* concanate string in the jQuery instantiation.